# Location finder along with updates using google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm new to android and i'm trying to develop an android application which includes tracking the user location details and showing it on a google map and the location should be updated in the map whenever it is changed. I'm unable to understand how to get this through google maps v2. They mentioned to change dependencies but i'm unable to find where to do that can anyone explain the usage of this with a simple example i tried to implement the steps given in below link but i'm unable to find project properties to edit
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show location of user on map when the change their location you need to take, Location API and Google Map API,

here is dependency link put in your app level gradel,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

Then after you need to start location service for update location on map also you need to initialise your map,

Here i consider You initialised your map show I am just showing how to use location api,

```
import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final float DISTANCE_FOR_FISPLACEMENT = 2; //here is the distance for update map in meter
    private Context context;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        if (checkPermsion(context)) {
            setupLocationService(context);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermsion(Context context) {
        int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void setupLocationService(Context context) {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
//                    .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            createLocationRequest();
        }
    }
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setFastestInterval(5 * 60 * 1000)
                .setInterval(5 * 60 * 1000)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(DISTANCE_FOR_FISPLACEMENT);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to onConnected");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        // Also here you can change your pin in map
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: is adding dependency in file sufficient or do i need to add any library functions?

Comment: my google play services installed is of version 39 is " compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'" correct for that version

Comment: No need to add any other library just put dependency which I listed, and if answer will help then vote up and accept it,

Comment: You set dependency version as per your sdk,

Comment: after adding the dependency i am getting configuration not correct error

Comment: Can you elaborate more your last  comment,